# how to cluster a nested list by a specific variable and do some statistics for other variables

Tags: python-3.x

I have a nested list sorted by the first element already, I want to rearrange the nested list based on the unique identifier ('a','b','c') and do some statistic calculations for other corresponding variables. below is what I have and what I want to get. Any hint? thanks.

## What I already have:

```
sortedlist=[['a',5,7],['a',3,5],['a',6,7],['b',3,7],['b',5,5],['b',6,9],['b',5,5],['c',1,9],['c',4,5]]
```

## What I want to get first:

```
target_list1[[['a','a','a'],[5,3,6],[7,5,7]],[['b','b','b','b'],[3,5,6,5],[7,5,9,5]],[['c','c'],[1,4],[9,5]]]
```

## What I want to get next:

```
target_list2[['a',median[5,3,6],median[7,5,7]],['b',median[3,5,6,5],median[7,5,9,5]],['c',median[1,4],median[9,5]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can use the [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) method. This will group your list of lists by a key function, in this case the first element of each list:

```
groups = itertools.groupby(sortedlist, operator.itemgetter(0))
```

This gives you tuples of keys and groups (which are iterators themselves). The expression `[list(g[1]) for g in groups]` will evaluate to:

```
[[['a', 5, 7], ['a', 3, 5], ['a', 6, 7]],
 [['b', 3, 7], ['b', 5, 5], ['b', 6, 9], ['b', 5, 5]],
 [['c', 1, 9], ['c', 4, 5]]]
```

Now you want to transpose that list of lists, and this can be done with the `zip()` function:

```
target_list1 = [list(zip(*g[1])) for g in groups]
```

This evaluates to:

```
[[('a', 'a', 'a'), (5, 3, 6), (7, 5, 7)],
 [('b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), (3, 5, 6, 5), (7, 5, 9, 5)],
 [('c', 'c'), (1, 4), (9, 5)]]
```

Next you want to apply your function to the result. As this is tagged with python3, we can use the statistics module:

```
>>> import statistics
>>> [ [l[0][0]] + [statistics.median(x) for x in l[1:]] for l in target_list1]
```

Bringing this all together:

```
import itertools
import operator
import statistics

target_list1 = [list(zip(*g[1])) 
                for g in itertools.groupby(sortedlist, operator.itemgetter(0))]
target_list2 = [ [l[0][0]] + [ statistics.median(x) for x in l[1:]] 
                 for l in target_list1]
```